# Is there an application to open links on another computer?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, url

I'm connecting from OSX to a Windows computer via RDP. I would like to click on links inside my RDP session and have the links open in a browser on my client computer. It feels like I could install some application on both ends and have them communicate over TCP and proxy the URL opening.

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [SendTab](http://sendtab.com/) on my MacBook Pro running Chrome, my Windows 7 machine running Chrome, and my iPhone running the SendTab app. There's also a Safari extension and a Firefox bookmarklet too, I think. Just install the extension and the tab that's opened in the respective browser will be sent to whichever browser you specify when you click the button. It's about a 1-3 second delay before it shows up in my testing.

It's not as seamless as clicking on the link in a Remote Desktop session, but it works really well if the links are already opened on the remote machine browser.

Plus, SendTab will keep a history of sent tabs and will queue them up if the recipient browser is not currently opened.

Comment: +1 This is awesome. Finally something I can use on all my machines and devices.

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know.
A workaround: copy the link and paste it on the other side into the run dialogue (WIN+R).

Comment: I have been doing doing copy/paste, it's really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Try a program like **[Clipboard Monitor](http://www.clipboardmonitor.de/download_en.htm)** (freeware) on your client PC - looks like it can automatically launch URLs it finds in the clipboard. Make sure your clipboard is shared in your RDP options, naturally.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the client is OSX so Clipboard Monitor won't work.